# Amazon SP API - Get product SKU by ASIN

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Using Amazon Selling Partner API, how can you get product's SKU number knowing only ASIN. I am not seller.

Tried different versions of "Catalog Items API", but none of them returns SKU in response.

Here, `GET /catalog/v0/items/{asin}` (`getCatalogItem`) has `SKUIdentifier` in response schema. But I don't have such key im my response.
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/catalog-items-api-v0-reference#identifiertype

Here is my response:
GET to `{{baseUrl}}/catalog/v0/items/:asin?MarketplaceId={{US_MarketplaceId}}`

```
{
    "payload": {
        "Identifiers": {
            "MarketplaceASIN": {
                "MarketplaceId": "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
                "ASIN": "B08S3G17TD"
            }
        },
        "AttributeSets": [
            ..........
```